# Why is Okta continually reauthenticating from Salesforce CPQ?

Tags: oauth, cpq

We just implemented Salesforce CPQ in Production and found that every time a user does anything that requires a call out to the server that CPQ is on... Okta wants to re-authenticate each time, which is a huge pain for the user.

Any idea if this is an issue with Okta or CPQ, and if so how to get around it?

Comment: It's probably an Okta issue, so you might want to contact their support, too, if you have not yet already.

Comment: Put in a case with Okta and Salesforce - Have not heard back from either yet.  Hard for me to believe that we are the only company in the world that uses Okta and CPQ.

Comment: Is this really something that nobody has heard of?